# Is there any exchange in stack overflow to guide writing economic paper?

Tags: discussion

Maybe it is off-topic. But I am wondering where in stack overflow that I can ask people some suggestions for some sentences or how to write an introduction and literature review for economics and finance papers with good tension.

Thank you in advance. I will close this topic and hope that I can receive the suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several guides available, here are those I know (and appreciate):

McCloskey Deirdre N., Economical Writing, Thirty-five rules for clear and persuasive prose, Third Edition
Neugeboren Robert H., 2005, The Student's Guide to Writing Economics, Routledge
Thomson William, 2011, A Guide for the Young Economist, MIT Press (2nd edition)

McCloskey also wrote an article available on her webpage:
http://www.deirdremccloskey.com/docs/pdf/Article_86.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The stack exchange format is not really for one on one guidance. The goal is to create a depository of knowledge that is useful for future visitors. For writing in general, there is [Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).